# How to filter an spreadsheet using filters + drop down feature in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've created an spreadsheet and I'd like to filter the information in the rows using a drop down filter. I've managed to create the drop down menu in A3 but now I'd like to show the information in the other columns (B3, C3, D3). I guess I need a formula and tried [some](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/drop-down-to-filter-data-rows-columns/) but still no solution. Thank you for your help!

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ytY1IfxRlujad2w6D_B1ggsUwqiwT6Vu_CHd-mY2DG4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, like this:

```
=iferror( filter(B4:D, A4:A = A3, len(A4:A)) )
```

The `iferror()` and `len()` bits are optional. The `len()` condition ensures that no row matches when `A3` is blank, and the `iferror()` wrapper hides the error that occurs then.

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) and [iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304).